# Data source name not found while running the unit test

Tags: c#, mstest, data-driven-tests

I am writing a data driven unit test. The input is an excel of type ".xlsx". I took reference from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms404700(v=vs.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN and used Odbc. Adding the code snippet below:

```
[TestMethod]        
[DataSource(
            "System.Data.Odbc",
            "Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};dbq=|DataDirectory|\\Data.xlsx;defaultdir=.;driverid=1046;fil=excel 12.0;maxbuffersize=2048;maxscanrows=8;pagetimeout=5;readonly=1;safetransactions=0;threads=3;uid=admin;usercommitsync=Yes",
            "Sheet1$",
            DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]        
[DeploymentItem("Folder\\Data.xlsx")]        
[Timeout(60000)]        
public void TestMethod1()
{
  
}
```

This is how the csproj of project look like:

```
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    
      <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
        <RuntimeIdentifier>win7-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
      </PropertyGroup>
      
      <-- Some dependencies -->

     <ItemGroup>
      <Content Include="..\..\..\Data.xlsx">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      </Content>
   </ItemGroup>
     
    </Project>
```

In local it's running perfectly fine, when I am running the build in msazure the unit test is failing with following error.

```
Error Message:
   The unit test adapter failed to connect to the data source or to read the data. For more information on troubleshooting this error, see "Troubleshooting Data-Driven Unit Tests" (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=62412) in the MSDN Library. Error details: ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the source file from excel to xml and used the below data driver.

```
[DeploymentItem("Data.xml")]
        [DataSource(
            "Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.XML",
            "|DataDirectory|\\Data.xml",
            "OracleParameters",
            DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]
```

This worked in the pipeline also.

Answer (score 0):

For there do not seem to be any populated `ItemGroup` attributes in your `csproj` I would assume that your `Data.xlsx` is not copied to the output dir when running the build on Azure.

Try adding:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <None Update="Folder\Data.xlsx">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

You can also do this via the SolutionExplorer -> Data.xlsx -> [RMB] -> Properties

Comment: I had this as well. I updated the csproj above. But i am having Build action as content. This also fails. I just fount out that in release folder Data.xlsx not getting created. Do you happen to know the reason?

Comment: Hard to tell without having more insight into Azure. At this point I cannot contribute anything else. But there are other questions dealing with [DeploymentItem on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=DeploymentItem) even if not Azure-specific. Might be worth checking them out.